# MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

Tags: mongodb

Hi am getting below error after starting spring boot application. I have already installed momgodb. Can someone please help me how to fix this.

2021-04-07 12:11:34.569  INFO 10268 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:439) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:407) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:27017
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:27017

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

```
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: Check whether the mongodb is running.

Comment: Yes, its running. I have started mongo db on a terminal.>                         
db.getMongo()
connection to 127.0.0.1:27017.                                                                            (base) gauravjain@Gauravs-MacBook-Pro.local:~$ brew services start mongodb-community
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)